# JQuery Ajax doesn't load a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a page into a  which is triggered by a click. Works fine without using click event or funtion, but if I add a some of that it doesn't work. I looked into some examples but a can't figure this out. Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#LoadByActivities').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ByActivities.aspx',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#TableContainer').html($(data).children('#todayActivitiesFor'));
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML Loaded

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div id="todayActivitiesFor">
        SOME TEXT
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML where it is received

```
<body>
    <form id="todayActivitiesForm" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="dia" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button Text="Enviar" ID="submit" runat="server" OnCommand="submitDate"/>
        <button id="LoadByActivities">Por Actividades</button><br />
        <div id="TableContainer"><asp:Table runat="server" ID="todayActivitiesTable"></asp:Table></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Any error in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Try changing `$('#LoadByActivities').on('click', function () {` to `$(document).on('click', '#LoadByActivities', function () {`

Comment: What does your data variable contain? How is the HTML organised?

Comment: I repeat when I delete .on('click') it works. It has something to do with the event handler

Comment: Q: Your code works as-is: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/d4xot706/1/. Is your page in the same folder as the ByActivities.aspx file as the ajax url is relative to the current page?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder. Everything works fine until I add on('click')

Comment: Followup: The `$(document).ready(function () {` shown in the example above was in fact *not present in the actual page*. It was a bit like extracting teeth but we got to the bottom of it eventually :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the entire page was shown it is obvious (and also one of the most common mistakes). The code precedes the elements it references.

You also need to stop the button from submitting the form as it is probably refreshing the page. Use `e.preventdefault()` for that.

With jQuery, you either have to place the code after the elements it references, or you need to wrap it in a DOM ready event handler. This will delay execution until all DOM elements have been loaded.

What is happening at the moment is `$('#LoadByActivities')` matches nothing because that element is still being loaded after the code has been run (the code gets run as it is found in the page).

Add a DOM ready handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#LoadByActivities').click(function (e) {
            // Stop the form submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ByActivities.aspx',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Ajax2");
                    $('#TableContainer').html($(data).find('#todayActivitiesFor'));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Ajax3");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** `$(function(){ YOUR CODE });` is just a handy shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){ YOUR CODE });`

Another alternative to DOM ready is to use a delegated event handler, attached to document (which is always present). The jQuery selector is only run at event time (not when the event is registered) so can work with elements that do not exist yet. *This is a bit more advanced though.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#LoadByActivities', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ByActivities.aspx',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Ajax2");
                $('#TableContainer').html($(data).find('#todayActivitiesFor'));
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Ajax3");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can replace the entire ajax call with `load()` (as load allows a selector expression after the url):

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#LoadByActivities').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#TableContainer').load('ByActivities.aspx #todayActivitiesFor');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That code work perfectly fine (I just added jQuery): http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rsqzfk2r/1/ Can you please show the entire page (everything, unedited including header and script includes) in the HTML window so I can spot an  problems? **Do not edit it at all, just save it**. Ignore any error from JSFiddle, I just need to see it. Thanks

Comment: Obvious now... You have no DOM ready handler around your code.

Comment: Now, alert("ajax2") is triggered but html isn't loaded.

Comment: Yeah it has the html, but it is not loaded to <div id="TableContainer"></div>

Comment: As a test, instead of `html()`, try `append()` `$('#TableContainer').empty().append($(data).find('#todayActivitiesFor'));` This should make no difference, but something odd is going on. Again please check F12 console for errors. A single typing mistake could break this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64006/discussion-on-answer-by-trueblueaussie-jquery-ajax-doesnt-load-a-page).

Comment: Is it possible that the page reloads and the content that is being bind to <div> erase itself? this is a stupid question but i noticed that if I make a lot of clicks on the button the content is shown for a second.

Comment: Put back the `e.preventdefault()` I had earlier. I have updated answer. Please use the chatroom conversation from now on. Link is on bluefeets first comment.